# Compare two files and return a true or false value

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two files with one column. 
If the first rows in the two files are same, then print 1 otherwise print 0.

`file1`:

```
M
A
A
M
```

`file2`:

```
M
M
A
A
```

`output`:

```
1
0
1
0
```

Can anybody show me an awk script which would do this?

Comment: What is field separater of two files?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$ awk '!NF{next} FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$1;next};{print $1==a[FNR]  ? 1 : 0}' file1 file2
1
0
1
0
```

**Explanation**

- `!NF{next}`: we don't need blank lines, skip it.
- `FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$1;next}`: while processing `file1`, we save its first field to associative array, with index is the line number.
- `{print $1==a[FNR]  ? 1 : 0}`: while processing `file2`, we check if the first field value equals with corresponding `file1` value, which saved in associative array `a`. If yes print 1 else print 0.

Answer (score 4):

```
paste file1 file2 | while read a b; do [[ $a != "$b" ]]; echo $?; done
```

the `[[` command returns a 0 status upon success and 1 on failure.